# Pre-create application environment in Argo CD

Tags: argocd, gitops

I need some hints how can one handle precreation of application needed resources. I.e. namespace the application will be running in. I know we can auto-create the namespace, but we don't want that and also we have another set of resources that we need to prepare for the app. Not to mention some task outside of the cluster.

I suppose the way is to use "app of apps", but not sure how these use cases are handled there. Is it possible to use it not only for Application CRD creation, but also for another resouces creation?(i.e. secrets, config map, even some external Azure ACR tokens).

It is actually about the whole app onboarding process utilizing ArgoCD's GitOps approach.

Comment: Inside one App, you can use **sync waves**: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/

Comment: Aren't they just for upgrades of application. Some steps can be run only once can you handle this with sync waves? Maybe the problem is I am trying to use gitops to setup the app, maybe such one-time task is better suited for some TF pipeline.

Comment: Aaah I hadn't understood your goal. Yes, definitely it's not for GitOps if these are one time task to do before deploying very first time. Do it in your setup pipeline. Optionally Helm can do things with hook but given your need I think it has to be managed outside of Kubernetes.

Comment: So you think to run ten setup task and then use "app of apps". The question is should I go full gitops or should I mix it.  We are fully terraformed now, but considering ArgoCD or other Gitops tooling. Thing is, if the required additional knowledge is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a resource dependency, you should leverage sync-waves. More info here https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/#how-does-it-work

Comment: forgot to read the comments before posting answer, someone else deserves the credit here.

Comment: FWIW - if you have a dependency on another application, then you can handle this with initContainers or readiness probes for your application - K8s is all about eventual consistency

Comment: I have dependency on resources outside of k8s stack.

Comment: if you have network access, then you should consider a PreSync Hook from ArgoCD or an initContainer for your pod

Answer (score 0):

@Zveratko
I think I almost have an identical case to yours. I am trying to deploy a SaaS app from a web page and I want to use a pure argocd gitops flow. Or a mix of some other tooling. Basically I want to start a tenant provisioning on a cluster with shared application (that already exists) and I want to add ingress for tenant's subdomain and possible DB instance if he wants data isolation and in the process I have to call my application tenant management api to register this tenant with this local application to enable domain name to tenant name resolution. So I first want to start with namespace deployment, intercept that and call my api with tenant registration data: adminemail, subdomain, isolateddbwanted, premiummoduleslist [m1,m2] and continue with ingress and possibly db deployment.

I have found several solutions. Maybe we can connect and explore these.

1. keptn-lifecycle-toolkit
https://isitobservable.io/observability/kubernetes/what-is-the-keptn-lifecycle-toolkit
it provides a way to add pre and post application (a custom crd which groups your workloads/deployments) installation hooks  and also pre and post hooks for your individual deployments
It can also do evaluation of your metrics and only install your workloads if the certain metrics is satisfied)

2. Write Custom Operator (Argo cd has a way to introspect your custom crd with lua script to check for Healthy status)

3. Write Custom web hook (your deployment can expose a web hook where you can do some things when you create some resource.

4. You can do helm or argo presync hooks to run a job
Argo: argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync and run some job
Helm:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: hook-preinstall
annotations:
"helm.sh/hook": "pre-install"

It is not easy to explain these here, but what I am saying is that you can still use pure argo cd approach and hook into synchronization flow at the right time and execute your preparation steps using custom code, script
(like in keptn lifecycle toolkit you can execute Deno script (runtime similar to nodejs) or python script